# @Schedule annotation run every few minutes (or seconds)

Tags: java, ejb, schedule

I would like to try to use the @Schedule annotation in the following way:

```
public class MyTestServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static JcanLogger LOG = JcanLoggerFactory.getLogger(ServiceTestServlet.class);

    @EJB CronService cronService;

    public void service(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws .... {
    ....
    cronService.iLive(); 
}
---
    @Local // because the ejb is in a servlet (there is no other jvm)
public interface CronService {

    public void iLive();
    public void runsEveryMinute();
}
---
@Singleton
public class CronServiceBean implements CronService {
    private static final JcanLogger LOG = JcanLoggerFactory.getLogger(CronServiceBean.class);

    @Schedule(minute="*")
    public void runsEveryMinute() {
        LOG.info(" runs EveryMinute ");
    }

    public void iLive() {
        LOG.info("iLive");

    }
 ---
 LOG
 ... 
 CronServiceBean:34  ] iLive
```

Based on the log, the CronService live and well, but the scheduled task 'runsEveryMinute' doesnt work.

How should it work using an EJB scheduled task?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

As per the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ejb/Schedule.html) for the `@Schedule` annotation, the default values are:

- `*` for all fields except hour, minute, and second; and
- `0` for hour, minute, and second, by default.

By specifying `minute="*"` and leaving hour at its default of `0`, it requests that the timer run every minute after midnight for one hour (i.e., 00:00, 00:01, 00:02, ..., 00:59) and then not again until the next day. Instead, use:

```
@Schedule(hour="*", minute="*")
```

To run every few seconds (e.g., `10` seconds), you can use a [cron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron)-like syntax:

```
@Schedule(hour = "*", minute = "*", second = "*/10", persistent = false)
```

By default, the scheduler persists events. Setting `persistent = false` will prevent them from building up over time, if so desired.

Answer (score 27):

Please find the following details for the scheduler configuration.

(1) To run every 1 min

```
@Schedule(hour = "*", minute = "*/1", persistent = false)
```

---

(2) To run every 5 mins

```
@Schedule(hour = "*", minute = "*/5", persistent = false)
```

---

(3) To run every 30 seconds

```
@Schedule(hour = "*", minute = "*", second = "*/30", persistent = false)
```

---

(4) To run every day at 6:00 am

```
@Schedule(hour = "6", minute = "0", second = "0", persistent = false)
```

---

(5) To run on every Friday at 2:00 pm

```
@Schedule(dayOfWeek = "Fri", hour = "14", persistent = false)
```

---

(6) To run on the first day of every month at 5:00 am

```
@Schedule(dayOfMonth="1", hour = "5", persistent = false)
```

I hope this information will help you to configure the scheduler as per your requirement.